# Postman is not adding headers programmatically

Tags: postman

Using Postman 5.5.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. I have the following pre-request script defined for my entire collection. My goal is to set a header on each request *at the collection level* without having to add it manually.

```
console.log('adding "Authorization: Token {{apiToken}}" header to current request');

pm.request.headers.add({
    key: 'Authorization',
    value: 'Token {{apiToken}}'
});
console.log(pm.request.headers);
```

I also tried setting the header value directly with `value: 'Token '+pm.environment.get('apiToken')`.

Neither approach actually adds it to the requests. The `pm.request.headers` is reporting that it's there, but come show time, it sure ain't. Here is the console output:

[image: no auth header sad panda]

I also tried adding `disabled: false` to the object passed to `add`, based on what's there if I add the header to a single request manually.

What's going on?

Comment: I don’t think that’s the way that works is it? Have you read some documentation on the Postman site that has told you that’s a valid way to add them? Could you not just add that directly to the headers section? That variable will be doing the same thing and getting set for the request. Add `Token {{apiToken}}` as the value on an Auth header.

Comment: I should've mentioned that I tried setting it directly using the value from `pm.environment` first. It was a long shot. Not that it matters now ;)

Comment: How are you capturing and storing the `apiToken` at the collection level, in order to reference this in the header?

Comment: Maybe duplicated from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131667/add-header-to-every-request-in-postman-in-pre-request-script)

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to use the `{{...}}` syntax in the `Pre-request Script` or `Tests` tab it's not going to set the environment variable value for you, as this can only be used in the URL, Headers and the Request body.

The way that you had it in your code, would always just be setting the `Authorization` key as the string - 'Token {{apiToken}}'.

A completely horrible way of getting the value would be this:

```
pm.request.headers.add({
    key: 'Authorization',
    value: `Token ${pm.environment.get('apiToken')}`
});
```

But again that's not going to set the header at the collection level.

You can add it as a global variable at the collection level in a `pre-request script` - This can then be added to each request.

Comment: I'm not seeing a collection-level Headers tab, that's the problem. There's an Authorization tab for collections which ended up working for me, though.

Comment: If you mentioned that you needed it at the Collection level more in the question -  I would have said that there ins't a tab yet, although it it a feature request that has been asked for on multiple occasions.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I must have been even more tired than I thought when I wrote that question up. D: Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: To be fair, I did say "I have the following pre-request script defined for my entire collection" in the original question. But I guess it wasn't so clear that my goal was to not have to manually edit each request. :P

Comment: :) Yeah I actually had to reread it again to see the 'collection' reference at the end of the sentence. So that method I proposed would work and set the header value correctly but because you don't want to edit each request manually it not going to work for you. You could export the Collection and do a `find/replace` and re import (not a nice workaround though)