# Add header to every request in Postman in pre-request script

Tags: postman

I want to automatically add a header to every request in my whole collection using this pre-request script:

```
pm.request.headers.add({
    'key': "myvar",
    'value': pm.environment.get("myvar")    
});
```

**myvar** is an environment variable.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For those who are trying it on postman ~ 7.10.0, you can add headers programmatically in a pre-request script, into the request or into the collection (into collection will add headers to all requests inside collection).

```js
pm.request.headers.add({ 
    // These keys appears when you set a header by hand. Just for fun they are here
    disabled: false,
    description:{
        content: "DescriptionTest",
        type: "text/plain"
    },
    // Your header, effectively
    key: 'KeyTest', 
    name: 'NameTest', 
    // If you set a variable you can access it
    // HeaderTest here has value="ValueHeaderTest"
    value: pm.collectionVariables.get("HeaderTest")
});
```

The code snippet generator **will not** show the added header:

```
GET /get_info.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.15.25:8001
Content-type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0
Accept: */*
Host: 192.168.15.25:8001
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

But the Postman Console will:

```
GET /get_info.php HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json
KeyTest: ValueHeaderTest
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0
Accept: */*
Host: 192.168.15.25:8001
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 23):

As of [Postman v7.0.9](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1947#issuecomment-477775232), this is now possible by adding a Pre-request Script on a collection.

To do this, go to your collection, right-click it, select Edit, and go to the `Pre-request Scripts` tab, where you can add your snippet, i.e.:

```
pm.request.headers.add({
  key: 'X-HEADER-TEST',
  value: '1'
});
```

Answer (score 12):

This certainly works. Loose the inverted commas on key and value

```
pm.request.headers.add({
    key: "myvar",
    value: pm.environment.get("myvar")    
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Looks like `pm.request.headers.add()` doesn't currently update the request being sent. It's been marked as a feature request: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4631

You might already know that you can create pre-set headers (from the Presets dropdown) to make setting your headers a little bit easier. And there's a couple options under Settings to include specific headers. But these suggestions don't automatically add a header to every request in the whole collection like you're asking about.

UPDATE: 
**[Postman added support for this in Postman App (v7.0.9)](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4631#issuecomment-485893751)**.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it but I am already using preset headers. I didn't know that this feature I'm asking for is not yet implemented, though.

Answer (score 9):

This copied from here, but it worked for me

https://gist.github.com/madebysid/b57985b0649d3407a7aa9de1bd327990

```
pm.sendRequest({
    url: "https://mydomain/ers/config/endpoint",
    method: 'GET',
    header: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json',
        //'x-site-code': pm.environment.get("x-site-code")
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'fetch'
    },
    body: {
        mode: 'raw'//,
        raw: JSON.stringify({ email: pm.environment.get("email"), password: pm.environment.get("password") })
    }
}, function (err, res) {

    pm.environment.set("X-CSRF-TOKEN", "Bearer " + res.json().token);
});
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks for putting reference link along with your answer.

Comment: Reference link no more valid now.

Answer (score 7):

Just add it in this way:

```js
pm.request.headers.add("x-api-key: value")
```

may using environment variable:

```js
pm.request.headers.add(`x-api-key: ${pm.environment.get("x-api-key")}`)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think may be you can try this way :

```
  // Add or update an existing header

 pm.request.headers.upsert({
 'key': "myvar",
 'value': pm.environment.get("myvar") 
 });
```

This was updated in Postman App (v7.0.9). For more reference you can refer to :
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1947

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. Headers are set as `disabled: true`

Answer (score 1):

In test section of login, use this script to remember token in Environment

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

tests["Body contains result"] = responseBody.has("result");

var result = jsonData.result

tests["result contains user"] = result.user !== null
var user = result.user
tests["result contains token"] = result.token !== null
var token = result.token
var accessToken = token.accessToken
var refreshToken = token.refreshToken

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("accessToken", accessToken);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("refreshToken", refreshToken);
```

in every call wihich requires token, use token like this in header section

```
Authorization = Bearer {{accessToken}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone on Postman > 10.0 that is having trouble getting this to work, make sure you don't also have the header set but disabled in the "Headers" tab of your request, otherwise the actual request will be missing the header when using `pm.request.headers.add` or `pm.request.headers.upsert`